# Locust - take response time out of RPS equation?

Tags: traffic, locust

This is the sort of traffic pattern I'm consistently seeing.

I understand that RPS roughly equals [number of users/(response time + sleep time)](https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1497), hence my RPS will be roughly flat if my number of users and my response times are increasing at a similar rate (I'm using 0 sleep time).

I also understand that you can't help me debug the underlying system whose response time is increasing! That's another thread I'll be pursuing separately. The increasing response time is **not** a Locust issue.

My question is how can I get Locust to **ignore response time**, in order to produce a constantly increasing RPS? I would like to take response time out of the equation entirely so that RPS is proportional to number of users.

(Why do I want to do this? In order to effectively load test my particular system.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An individual Locust user is syncronous/sequential and cannot ”ignore response times” any more than any other Python program can ”ignore the time spent executing a line of code”

But you can use wait_time = constant_pacing(seconds_per_iteration) to ensure a fixed iteration time for each user https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#wait-time-attribute

Or wait_time = constant_pacing(1/iterations_per_second) if you prefer.

For a ”global” version of the same type of wait, use https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/constant_total_ips_ex.py

Make sure your user count is high enough, as none of these methods can launch additional users/concurrent requests.

You may also want to have a look at https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ#increase-my-request-raterps

Comment: Is there an alternative tool to locust that will achieve fire requests without depending on response time. And are we missing some other concepts here to better tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Building on cyberwiz's answer, you can't make the individual Locust users ignore response time. Each has made a request and can't do anything else until it gets a response. With ever increasing response times, all you can do is make Locust spawn more and more users. You'd need to run in distributed mode and add more workers who can spawn more users. You can specify a higher user count and maybe even a higher hatch rate, depending on the behavior you're trying to achieve.